# How to find source location of method in cucumber-ruby?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

Not able to find the source location of the method in cucumber-ruby

I have tried in env.rb file

```
Before do |scenario|
 puts scenario.name  
end
```

I don't know where the "name" method defined?

There is no method named "name" in https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/Cucumber/RunningTestCase/Scenario

Comment: Can you please do `puts scenario.class` to get class name, because I suggesting that `Cucumber::RunningTestCase::Scenario` is not the class we are looking for. It can be https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/Cucumber/Formatter/LegacyApi/Ast/Scenario for example.

Answer (score 1):

`Scenario` is a [`SimpleDelegator`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) which means that any method that is not defined will be passed on to the delegation object. This delegation object is set here using `super test_case`

```
# lib/cucumber/running_test_case.rb
def initialize(test_case, result = Core::Test::Result::Unknown.new)
  @test_case = test_case
  @result = result
  super test_case
end
```

Since `name` is not defined by `Scenario` it belongs to the injected object `test_case` in this instance.

You can determine what the delegation object is by using `SimpleDelegator#__getobj__` like so

```
scenario.__getobj__.class
```

To determine where the `name` method comes from you can attempt to use [`Method#source_location`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Method.html#method-i-source_location) like so:

```
scenario.__getobj__.method(:name).source_location
```

However, if this method is dynamically defined (or defined in a `C` code extension) then this will simply return `nil` and you will have to look at the documentation and/or source code for the `scenario.__getobj__.class` object to determine how it defines `name`.

Comment: "name" method is defined in "lib/cucumber/core/test/case.rb"  
`class Scenario < SimpleDelegator
      def initialize(test_case, result = Core::Test::Result::Unknown.new)
        @test_case = test_case
        @result = result
        super test_case
      end
end 
`
But "Scenario" class is not subclass of "case" class, then how "case" class methods are available in Scenario class object?

Comment: I don't mean to be impertinent but did you read my answer? I thought I explained this fairly well along with offering documentation you can review